# In my javascript file there are two methods that contains another method that contain same name and when that function is called working Confusingly

Tags: javascript, signalr, webrtc, simple-peer

```
const video = document.querySelector('video');
let client = {};
var stream;


navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, function (stream) {
    stream = stream;
}, function () { })
    .then(stream => {
        connection.invoke('NewVideoClient');
        video.srcObject = stream
        video.play();


        function InitPeer(type) {
            var peer = new SimplePeer({
                initiator: (type == 'init') ? true : false,
                stream: stream,
                trickle: false
            });

            peer.on('stream', function (stream) {
                CreateVideo(stream);
            });

            peer.on('connect', () => {
                console.log('CONNECT');
                alert('CONNECT');
            });

            //peer.on('close', function () {
            //    document.getElementById('peerVideo').remove();
            //    peer.destroy();

            //});
            return peer;
        }


        // for peer type init
        function CreatePeer() {
            alert("Enter in to CreatePeer");
            client.gotAnswer = false;
            let peer = InitPeer('init');
           // let data = null;
            peer.on('signal', function (data) {
                if (!client.gotAnswer) {
                    connection.invoke('SendOffer', data);
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                }

            });
            client.peer = peer;

        }

        //peer not init to pass the answer
        function CreateAnswer(offer) {
            let peer = InitPeer('notInit');
            let data = null;
            peer.on('signal', (offer) => {
                alert("Enter in to CreateAnswer");
                connection.invoke('SendAnswer', offer);
            });
            peer.signal(offer);
        }

        //this fuction will run when answer send from server
        function SignalAnswer(answer) {
            alert("Enter in to Signaling");
            client.gotAnswer = true;
            let peer = client.peer;
            peer.signal(answer);

        };

        //this function will create video
        function CreateVideo(stream) {
            alert("video play");
            let video = document.createElement('video');
            video.id = 'peerVideo';
            video.style.width = '400px';
            video.style.height = '400px';
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.class = 'embed-responsive-item';
            document.querySelector("#peerDiv").appendChild(video);
            video.play();
        }


        function SessionActive() {
            document.write("User is in another call.Please come back");
        }

        //Hub will call this function to create the offer
        connection.on("CreateOffer", function () {
            alert("Enter in to CreateOffer");
            CreatePeer();
        });

        //Hub will call this method to create the answer
        connection.on("CreateAnswer", function (offer) {
            alert("Enter in to CreateAnswer");
            CreateAnswer(offer);
        });


        //Hub will call this fucntion to send the answer ot the caller
        connection.on("SignalAnswer", function (answer) {
            alert("Enter in to Signaling");
            SignalAnswer(answer);

        })

        //Hub will call this fuction to this connect the video 
        connection.on("RemovePeer", function () {

            document.getElementById('peerVideo').remove();
            if (client.peer) {
                client.peer.destroy();
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(err => document.write(err));
```

I have written 3 methods in my video chat application as I new to javascript there is a small confusion. In method "SignalAnswer" it call "peer.signal(answer)" and this calls to the signal function inside "CreatePeer". Inside "CreateAnswer" method also there is a signal function created but it is not called. it will be call by  peer.signal(offer) in side the same method. My guess  is because peer will get two different objects in two different time. So according to the object assign this function will be called.Can any one explain about this. how these functions are working in javascripts 
NOTE : Connection is used to call the SingnalR hub.

Comment: You haven't posted all the relevant code so we can't really say. Where are the 3 main functions being used/instantiated?

Comment: @Scott Marcus I have entered whole java script code.  in there connection object is used to keep the connection with SignalR hub.